# Pytest: Test a function that gets input from the user and calls another function based on that input

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, pytest

I've coded a python app and designed it like pages (almost every function represent a page)

Lets say that every page (function) has some menu options and expect some input (example: b. Back | s. Save)

Based on that input (choosing an option) my function is going to call one of different functions.

For simplicity, lets say this is the function:

```
def func():
    while True:
        try:
            choice = input("choose one option: ")

            if choice == "b":
                return go_back()
            
            elif choice == "s":
                return save()
            
            else:
                raise ValueError
            
        except: ValueError
            print("Invalid Input")
```

Is there a way to test this function with pytest library (as I know, to test functions, they need to be returning some values)

Or should I change the whole architecture ?

I have no idea how this can be tested by pytest !

Answer (score 0):

Mock the `input` function in your test.  Here's an example with a simpler version of your `func()`:

```
def func():
    while True:
        choice = input("choose one option: ")
        if choice == "b":
            return True
        elif choice == "s":
            return False


from unittest.mock import patch

@patch('test.input')
def test_func(mock_input):
    # Test one 'b' input
    mock_input.return_value = "b"
    assert func() is True

    # Test one 's' input
    mock_input.return_value = "s"
    assert func() is False

    # Test two wrong inputs followed by 'b'
    mock_input.side_effect = "wrong", "nope", "b"
    assert func() is True
```

Note that I patched `'test.input'` because my `func` is in a module called `test.py` -- make sure when you `patch` that you specify the patch target relative to the module that you're testing.

In the final part of the test, I assign an iterable to `Mock.side_effect`, which takes the place of `return_value` and lets me provide a different return value for each subsequent call to the mock, so I can exercise the looping part of `func` and test that it will call `input` repeatedly.  If I just set `mock_input.return_value = "wrong"`, `func()` would loop infinitely because the mocked `input` call would never return anything else!

Running this with `pytest`:

```
C:\test\python>pytest test.py
================================================ test session starts =================================================
platform win32 -- Python 3.10.5, pytest-7.1.2, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: C:\test\python
plugins: cov-3.0.0, dotenv-0.5.2
collected 1 item

test.py .                                                                                                       [100%]

================================================= 1 passed in 0.06s ==================================================
```